# Unable to use file upload component inside other component

Tags: vue.js, event-handling

I have a photoUpload component. I want to use photoUpload component in other components. I have input field to select file in photoUpload component.I used event bus to pass function from one component to other components. When I select the file , it call the function and I want to pass that function to other components along with the selected file. Here is my code.
Please help me.
PhotoUpload.vue

```
 <input type="file" id="file" @input-change="onInputChange" multiple />
```

```
  onInputChange(e) {
      const files = e.target.files;
      this.$root.$emit("on-input-change", files);
    },
```

Test.vue

```
  created() {
  this.$root.$on("on-input-change", this.onInputChange)
  },
methods: {
   onInputChange(value) {
          alert(2);
          this.documents = value;
          console.log(this.documents);debugger;          
        // Array.from(files).forEach(file => this.addImage(file));
     },
}
```

Comment: Are they siblings? Is event bus solution shown above working for you?

Comment: They are in different folders. I'm able to pass value but i'm trying to pass function . @StarkButtowski

Comment: Can you explain more on the use case of passing a function to components?

Comment: Actually I have many components having forms with image field.And I want to use the photoUpload components in all the components for image upload in other forms as well. I tried by passing function but actually i don't have idea how can I solve it. @StarkButtowski

Comment: photoUpload component is in one folder and other components are in other folder. How can I reuse input field for file upload in other components? @StarkButtowski